# Spring security Oauth2 set different token per browser tap

Tags: java, cookies, spring-oauth2, httpcookie

I want to get different token per browser tap to get differents roles and user logged against oauth server in the same browser

I have requested oauth login against own oauth server. I develop own client using Spring security Oauth2...

OAUTHCONF.JAVA

Spring security client...

```
/**
     * Called after executed Configuration "addFilterBefore"
     *
     * @return OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter
     */
    private OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter oauthFilter() {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter oauthFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter("/login");

        // OAuth2RestTemplate > Spring Boot does not automatically create such a bean,
        OAuth2RestTemplate oauthTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(oauth(), oauth2ClientContext);
        UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(oauthResource().getUserInfoUri(), oauth().getClientId());
        tokenServices.setRestTemplate(oauthTemplate);

        oauthFilter.setRestTemplate(oauthTemplate);
        oauthFilter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);

        return oauthFilter;
    }
```

oauth configuration...

```
@Autowired
    private OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("oauth.resource")
    public ResourceServerProperties oauthResource() {
        return resourceServerProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("oauth.client")
    public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails oauth() {
        return authorizationCodeResourceDetails;
    }
```

INDEX.HTML
View...

```
if (oauth2ClientContext!=null && oauth2ClientContext.getAccessToken()!=null) {
            labelInformation.setText("Access token > " + oauth2ClientContext.getAccessToken());
        }
```

In this mode, in the first tap I have requested the token. In the second tab shows me directly token... Is there a way to request different token via Spring security per tab?

Comment: What do you mean by 'browser tap'? typo for tab? Anyway, after Spring authenticates and authorises a user, it will create a session. The session (cookie) is visible in all tabs (opened the same application URL context).

Comment: It was a typo... I meant "tab". Yes. Anyway, is there a way to create different session (cookie sessions) per tab? Simulating aouth login browser or differents curl request? I'm searching clues to find out it... Thanks! :)